# How do I check if the Chrome browser supports the screenshot feature in the manifest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Google Chrome has added support for screenshots in the manifest. How can I tell if my browser is Chrome and supports this feature?

https://web.dev/add-manifest/#description

[image]